# JS : Use variable in grep filter

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please help on how to use variable in Grep filter..
the `return n.state_id == 1 || n.state_id == 3;` works but if it's inside a variable it's not working.

```js
var json_data = [{"id":147,"state_id":1,"value":1}, {"id":147,"state_id":1,"value":4},{"id":147,"state_id":2,"value":1}, {"id":147,"state_id":3,"value":1}];

$filter_state = ['1','3'];
var state_filter = '';
for (let key in $filter_state){
var operator_key = key==0 ? '' :  ' || ';
    state_filter+= operator_key + 'n.state_id == ' + $filter_state[key] + '';
}
jQuery('#state_filter').html(state_filter);

// This one works
var filter_1 = $.grep( json_data, function( n, i) {
  return n.state_id == 1 || n.state_id == 3;
});
console.log(filter_1);

// This is one is not
var filter_2 = $.grep( json_data, function( n, i) {
  return state_filter;
});
console.log(filter_2);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

State Filter: <div id="state_filter"></div>
```

Comment: Why not use Array `filter` method instead.

Comment: `state_filter` is a string, not a JS expression. You could use `eval` to use the JS expression, but there are other, simpler ways as suggested

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava  `eval` is certainly not needed or wanted here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is ZERO need for jQuery here

NOTE I changed the states to ints. If you want to keep them strings, you will need to cast the state_id to string too

```js
var json_data = [{"id":147,"state_id":1,"value":1}, {"id":147,"state_id":1,"value":4},{"id":147,"state_id":2,"value":1}, {"id":147,"state_id":3,"value":1}];

const filter_states = [1, 3];
const filter_2 = json_data.filter(({state_id}) => filter_states.includes(state_id))
console.log(filter_2);
```

If you MUST use $.grep, then you can use the same test

```
const filter_states = [1, 3];
const filter_2 = $.grep( json_data, function( n, i) {
  return filter_states.includes(n.state_id)
});
```

If you want to define the item to test beforehand, do so

```
const filterArr = [1, 3];
const item = "state_id";
const filter_2 = $.grep( json_data, function( n, i) {
  return filterArr.includes(n[item])
});
```

Comment: I updated with how to pass the item you want to test too, to keep the grep without hardcoded array and value

Answer (score 0):

according to documentation :

> The $.grep() method removes items from an array as necessary so that
> all remaining items pass a provided test. The test is a function that
> is passed an array item and the index of the item within the array.
> *Only if the test **returns true** will the item be in the result array.*

so in `filter_1` the result of expression is `true` or `false`
but in `filter_2` the State Filter is a string and a string is always `true` (empty string is false).

therefore in filter_2 all items will be passed.